# wait for ASHX image to load using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ashx

I'm using the follow code to load an image from an ASHX page.  The Image is generated on the server from the parameter in the query string, in fact it is a Word document that is created similar to an invoice and converted into an PNG image.  The current process takes about 2 seconds to populate the browser on the first loading and if changes are made to the data a reload takes about a second.  I would like to give the user a wait image while it is loading but can figure out how to call it.

```
            var memberID = '12345';
            var biosketchID = '890';

            var d = new Date();
            var n = d.getMilliseconds();
            $("#theImg").attr("src", "https://somewhere.com/app/CreateDoc_image.ashx?p1=" + memberID + "&p2=" + biosketchID + "&p3=I&p4" + n);
```

I'm also adding a time to my query string so that the browser does not cache the image.  How can I do a popup wait for this process?  Thanks

Comment: "I'm also adding a time to my query string so that the browser does not cache the image" - you could add HTTP Cache-Control headers to the ASHX instead, if you control that. For the spinner, it looks like you can add a [load event to images](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) but it may not be 100% reliable.

Comment: I'll check that out- thanks